# Ignore some errors from bindFromRequest

Tags: forms, validation, playframework-2.0

I have a special input form (a select multiple) with the name "allergies" on my form, but it returns an error if I do :

```
Form<Child> form = form(Child.class).bindFromRequest();
```

from my server side, with "Invalid value" error.

For it to almost work, I should rename my field to "allergies.id" but I can't change it.

So I wanted to ignore this field for errors, and did something like :

```
form.field("allergies").errors().clear()
```

but then, if I do a

```
if (form.hasErrors())
```

it returns true, just for allergies.

How can I ignore the validation of allergies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's very clever to manipulate the list. A more clean way is to bind only the fields you want. `public Form<T> bind(Map<String,String> data, String... allowedFields) {`.

How ever form.field("allergies").errors().clear() can't work, because the you have an error map where for the key 'allergies' exists an empty list. `form.errors().remove("allergies");` should work.

Comment: Must be `errors()` see http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/java/play/data/Form.html#errors()

Comment: could you explain why `.clear()` wouldn't work but `.remove()` would?

Comment: you must work on the HashMap of the form not of the List of the field.

Comment: Well, after that, if I removed an error, `form.get()` returns me a `[IllegalStateException: No value]` :/

Comment: Yes of course I forgotten this. If there was validation errors, the get doesn't work, that's the reason, why their always should be an hasErrors() before get. Sorry I was to focused on the hack that I didn't thought, about site-effects.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
 form.discardErrors();
```

Comment: Note in scala it's `discardingErrors` and it works as intended.